# C: get sizeof typedef struct array inside of function when passed as parameter

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have a bit of code here that I wrote that demonstrates a problem I am having.

I am getting a different value for sizeof when I do sizeof of a pointer that represents a struct array. I think that when I do sizeof inside the function, it is just the sizeof the pointer, rather than the sizeof the array itself.

so here is my question: Is there any way to get the sizeof of a typedef struct array from inside of a function when it is passed in as a pointer?

```
#include <printf.h>
 
typedef struct {
    int value_1;
    int value_2;
} example_struct_t; 

example_struct_t struct_a[] = {
    {
        .value_1 = 4,
        .value_2 = 0,
    },
    {
        .value_1 = 8,
        .value_2 = 9,
    },
};

void printsizeof(example_struct_t *struct_array){
    printf("size of struct_array inside func: %lu\r\n", sizeof struct_array);
}

int main() {
    printf("This demo shows that a typedef struct array shows a different size inside of main vs inside of a function:\r\n");
    printf("sizeof struct_array outside func: %lu\r\n", sizeof struct_a);
    printsizeof(struct_a);
    return 1;
}
```

this is how it is compiled and the terminal output:

```
~/
❯ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror struct_size_bug.c -o struct_size_bug

~/
❯ ./struct_size_bug                                                                 
This demo shows that a typedef struct array shows a different size inside of main vs inside of a function:
sizeof struct_array outside func: 16
size of struct_array inside func: 8
```

Comment: You can't get the size of an array from a pointer.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, but is there any way to pass in an array as an argument, where you can get the size?

Comment: @cosmikwolf – No.  That's what "you can't get the size of an array from a pointer" means.

Comment: You can pass an *extra* argument, where you can provide the number of items. There's really no way around it.

Comment: or pass a struct containing the address of the array and the size of the array, similar to `std::array` in C++